# How to code Realtime (Instant) Payment Notification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, payment-gateway

I faced some issue when integrate the payment gateway especially in Realtime Payment Notification

In the testing environment, once we done the payment, the Merchant will receive server to server notification in realtime.

The realtime notification will be a HTTP POST from Bank server to the Response URL that Merchant had set.

Now what i don't really understand is where should i put my Response URL code, and how do i code the Response URL in order to receive the payment notification from Bank in JSON format